# How to view the Intents a BroadcastReceiver is receiving?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, infinite-loop

I have an infinite loop somewhere in my code, indicative of my group messaging BroadcastReceiver continually accepting only the first message in the database, over and over again, until I stop running the application. Note that the repeating of the message only occurs in the client app and not in the server database.

Is there way to trace what intent the BroadcastReceiver is receiving? ie. be able to view the intents the BroadcastReceiver is acting on to locate the source of these actions?

My code for both sending and receiving a group message if it helps: (BroadcastReceiver is near the bottom)

```
public class GroupMessaging extends Activity {

    private static final int MESSAGE_CANNOT_BE_SENT = 0;
    public String username;
    public String groupname;

    private EditText messageText;
    private EditText messageHistoryText;
    private Button sendMessageButton;
    private Manager imService;
    private InfoOfGroup group = new InfoOfGroup();
    private StorageManipulater localstoragehandler;
    private Cursor dbCursor;

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            imService = ((MessagingService.IMBinder) service).getService();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            imService = null;
            Toast.makeText(GroupMessaging.this, R.string.local_service_stopped,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.message); // messaging_screen);

        messageHistoryText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageHistory);

        messageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);

        messageText.requestFocus();

        sendMessageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendMessageButton);

        Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();

        group.groupName = extras.getString(InfoOfGroup.GROUPNAME);
        group.groupId = extras.getString(InfoOfGroup.GROUPID);
        String msg = extras.getString(InfoOfGroupMessage.GROUP_MESSAGE_TEXT);

        setTitle("Group: " + group.groupName);

        // Retrieve the information
        localstoragehandler = new StorageManipulater(this);
        dbCursor = localstoragehandler.groupGet(group.groupId);

        if (dbCursor.getCount() > 0) {

            int noOfScorer = 0;
            dbCursor.moveToFirst();

            while ((!dbCursor.isAfterLast())
                    && noOfScorer < dbCursor.getCount()) {
                noOfScorer++;

                // String 2: Username
                // String 3: Message
                this.appendToMessageHistory(dbCursor.getString(2),
                        dbCursor.getString(3));
                dbCursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        localstoragehandler.close();

        if (msg != null) {
            // Then friends username and message, not equal to null
            this.appendToMessageHistory(group.groupId, msg);
            ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE))
                    .cancel((group.groupId + msg).hashCode());
        }

        // The send button
        sendMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            CharSequence message;
            Handler handler = new Handler();

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                message = messageText.getText();
                if (message.length() > 0) {

                    appendToMessageHistory(imService.getUsername(),
                            message.toString());

                    // *****************PROBLEM MAY BE
                    // HERE******************************
                    localstoragehandler.groupInsert(imService.getUsername(),
                            group.groupId, message.toString());

                    messageText.setText("");
                    Thread thread = new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {

                                if (imService.sendGroupMessage(group.groupId,
                                        group.groupName, message.toString()) == null) {

                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                        public void run() {

                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                                    R.string.message_cannot_be_sent,
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                            // showDialog(MESSAGE_CANNOT_BE_SENT);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        R.string.message_cannot_be_sent,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    thread.start();
                }
            }
        });

        messageText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == 66) {
                    sendMessageButton.performClick();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        int message = -1;
        switch (id) {
        case MESSAGE_CANNOT_BE_SENT:
            message = R.string.message_cannot_be_sent;
            break;
        }

        if (message == -1) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(GroupMessaging.this)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {
                                    /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                                }
                            }).create();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(groupMessageReceiver);
        unbindService(mConnection);

        ControllerOfGroup.setActiveGroup(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        bindService(new Intent(GroupMessaging.this, MessagingService.class),
                mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter();
        i.addAction(MessagingService.TAKE_GROUP_MESSAGE);

        registerReceiver(groupMessageReceiver, i);

        ControllerOfGroup.setActiveGroup(group.groupName);
    }

    // For receiving messages from other users...
    public class GroupMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
            String username = extra.getString(InfoOfGroupMessage.FROM_USER);
            String groupId = extra.getString(InfoOfGroupMessage.TO_GROUP_ID);
            String message = extra
                    .getString(InfoOfGroupMessage.GROUP_MESSAGE_TEXT);

            // *************************OR HERE******************************
            if (username != null && message != null) {
                if (group.groupId.equals(groupId)) {
                    appendToMessageHistory(username, message);
                    localstoragehandler.groupInsert(username, groupId, message);

                } else {
                    if (message.length() > 15) {
                        message = message.substring(0, 15);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(GroupMessaging.this,
                            username + " says '" + message + "'",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Build receiver object to accept messages
    private GroupMessageReceiver groupMessageReceiver = new GroupMessageReceiver();

    // Setting username and message to the message box
    public void appendToMessageHistory(String username, String message) {
        if (username != null && message != null) {
            messageHistoryText.append(username + ":\n");
            messageHistoryText.append(message + "\n");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (localstoragehandler != null) {
            localstoragehandler.close();
        }
        if (dbCursor != null) {
            dbCursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

MessagingService Class:

```
public class MessagingService extends Service implements Manager, Updater {
    // private NotificationManager mNM;

    public static String USERNAME;
    public static final String TAKE_MESSAGE = "Take_Message";
    public static final String FRIEND_LIST_UPDATED = "Take Friend List";
    public static final String MESSAGE_LIST_UPDATED = "Take Message List";

    public static final String TAKE_GROUP_MESSAGE = "Take_Group_Message";
    public static final String GROUP_LIST_UPDATED = "Take Group List";
    public static final String GROUP_MESSAGE_LIST_UPDATED = "Take Group Message List";

    public ConnectivityManager conManager = null;
    private final int UPDATE_TIME_PERIOD = 15000;

    private String rawFriendList = new String();
    private String rawMessageList = new String();

    private String rawGroupList = new String();
    private String rawGroupMessageList = new String();

    SocketerInterface socketOperator = new Socketer(this);

    private final IBinder mBinder = new IMBinder();
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String groupname;
    private boolean authenticatedUser = false;
    // timer to take the updated data from server
    private Timer timer;

    private StorageManipulater localstoragehandler;

    private NotificationManager mNM;

    public class IMBinder extends Binder {
        public Manager getService() {
            return MessagingService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        localstoragehandler = new StorageManipulater(this);

        conManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        new StorageManipulater(this);

        // Timer is used to take the friendList info every UPDATE_TIME_PERIOD;
        timer = new Timer();

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Random random = new Random();
                int tryCount = 0;
                while (socketOperator.startListening(10000 + random
                        .nextInt(20000)) == 0) {
                    tryCount++;
                    if (tryCount > 10) {
                        // if it can't listen a port after trying 10 times, give
                        // up...
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    private void showNotification(String username, String msg) {
        // Set the icon, scrolling text and TIMESTAMP
        String title = "AndroidIM: You got a new Message! (" + username + ")";

        String text = username + ": "
                + ((msg.length() < 5) ? msg : msg.substring(0, 5) + "...");

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                .setContentTitle(title).setContentText(text);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, IndividualMessaging.class);
        i.putExtra(InfoOfFriend.USERNAME, username);
        i.putExtra(InfoOfMessage.MESSAGETEXT, msg);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        mBuilder.setContentText("New message from " + username + ": " + msg);

        // Send the notification.
        // We use a layout id because it is a unique number. We use it later to
        // cancel.
        mNM.notify((username + msg).hashCode(), mBuilder.build());
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public String sendMessage(String username, String tousername, String message)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String params = "username=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.username, "UTF-8")
                + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.password, "UTF-8")
                + "&to=" + URLEncoder.encode(tousername, "UTF-8") + "&message="
                + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8") + "&action="
                + URLEncoder.encode("sendMessage", "UTF-8") + "&";
        Log.i("PARAMS", params);
        return socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);
    }

    private String getFriendList() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        // after authentication, server replies with friendList xml

        // Has the friend and group and message(s) xml
        rawFriendList = socketOperator
                .sendHttpRequest(getAuthenticateUserParams(username, password));
        if (rawFriendList != null) {
            this.parseFriendInfo(rawFriendList);
        }
        return rawFriendList;
    }

    private String getMessageList() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        rawMessageList = socketOperator
                .sendHttpRequest(getAuthenticateUserParams(username, password));
        if (rawMessageList != null) {
            this.parseMessageInfo(rawMessageList);
        }
        return rawMessageList;
    }

    private String getGroupList() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        rawGroupList = socketOperator
                .sendHttpRequest(getAuthenticateUserParams(username, password));
        if (rawGroupList != null) {
            this.parseGroupInfo(rawGroupList);
        }
        return rawGroupList;
    }

    private String getGroupMessageList() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        rawGroupMessageList = socketOperator
                .sendHttpRequest(getAuthenticateUserParams(username, password));
        if (rawGroupMessageList != null) {
            this.parseGroupInfo(rawGroupMessageList);
        }
        return rawGroupMessageList;
    }

    public String authenticateUser(String usernameText, String passwordText)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        this.username = usernameText;
        this.password = passwordText;

        this.authenticatedUser = false;

        String result = null;

        result = this.getFriendList(); // socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(getAuthenticateUserParams(username,
                                        // password));

        if (result != null && !result.equals(LoggingIn.AUTHENTICATION_FAILED)) {
            // if user is authenticated then return string from server is not
            // equal to AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
            this.authenticatedUser = true;
            rawFriendList = result;
            USERNAME = this.username;

            // For Friends
            Intent i = new Intent(FRIEND_LIST_UPDATED);
            i.putExtra(InfoOfFriend.FRIEND_LIST, rawFriendList);
            sendBroadcast(i);

            // For Groups
            Intent iG = new Intent(GROUP_LIST_UPDATED);
            i.putExtra(InfoOfGroup.GROUP_LIST, rawGroupList);
            sendBroadcast(iG);

            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // rawFriendList = IMService.this.getFriendList();
                        // sending friend list
                        Intent i = new Intent(FRIEND_LIST_UPDATED);
                        Intent i2 = new Intent(MESSAGE_LIST_UPDATED);
                        Intent i3 = new Intent(GROUP_LIST_UPDATED);
                        Intent i4 = new Intent(GROUP_MESSAGE_LIST_UPDATED);

                        String tmp = MessagingService.this.getFriendList();
                        String tmp2 = MessagingService.this.getMessageList();

                        String tmp3 = MessagingService.this.getGroupList();
                        String tmp4 = MessagingService.this
                                .getGroupMessageList();

                        // For friends
                        if (tmp != null) {
                            i.putExtra(InfoOfFriend.FRIEND_LIST, tmp);
                            sendBroadcast(i);
                            Log.i("friend list broadcast sent ", "");

                            if (tmp2 != null) {
                                i2.putExtra(InfoOfMessage.MESSAGE_LIST, tmp2);
                                sendBroadcast(i2);
                                Log.i("friend list broadcast sent ", "");
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.i("friend list returned null", "");
                        }

                        // Changed to i3 and i4 for the intents created...
                        if (tmp3 != null) {
                            i3.putExtra(InfoOfGroup.GROUP_LIST, tmp3);
                            sendBroadcast(i3);
                            Log.i("group list broadcast sent ", "");

                            if (tmp4 != null) {
                                i4.putExtra(
                                        InfoOfGroupMessage.GROUP_MESSAGE_LIST,
                                        tmp4);
                                sendBroadcast(i4);
                                Log.i("group list broadcast sent ", "");
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.i("group list returned null", "");
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, UPDATE_TIME_PERIOD, UPDATE_TIME_PERIOD);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void messageReceived(String username, String message) {

        // FriendInfo friend = FriendController.getFriendInfo(username);
        InfoOfMessage msg = IndividualMessageController.checkMessage(username);
        if (msg != null) {
            Intent i = new Intent(TAKE_MESSAGE);

            i.putExtra(InfoOfMessage.USERID, msg.userid);
            i.putExtra(InfoOfMessage.MESSAGETEXT, msg.messagetext);
            sendBroadcast(i);
            String activeFriend = ControllerOfFriend.getActiveFriend();
            if (activeFriend == null || activeFriend.equals(username) == false) {
                localstoragehandler.insert(username, this.getUsername(),
                        message.toString());
                showNotification(username, message);
            }

            Log.i("TAKE_MESSAGE broadcast sent by im service", "");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void groupMessageReceived(String username, String groupId,
            String message) {

        // FriendInfo friend = FriendController.getFriendInfo(username);
        InfoOfGroupMessage msg = GroupMessageController.checkMessage(username);
        if (msg != null) {
            Intent i = new Intent(TAKE_GROUP_MESSAGE);

            i.putExtra(InfoOfGroupMessage.FROM_USER, msg.fromUser);
            i.putExtra(InfoOfGroupMessage.TO_GROUP_ID, msg.toGroupId);
            i.putExtra(InfoOfGroupMessage.GROUP_MESSAGE_TEXT, msg.messageText);

            sendBroadcast(i);
        }

        Log.i("TAKE_GROUP_MESSAGE broadcast sent by im service", "");
    }

    private String getAuthenticateUserParams(String usernameText,
            String passwordText) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String params = "username="
                + URLEncoder.encode(usernameText, "UTF-8")
                + "&password="
                + URLEncoder.encode(passwordText, "UTF-8")
                + "&action="
                + URLEncoder.encode("authenticateUser", "UTF-8")
                + "&port="
                + URLEncoder.encode(
                        Integer.toString(socketOperator.getListeningPort()),
                        "UTF-8") + "&";

        return params;
    }

    public void setUserKey(String value) {
    }

    public boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        return conManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    }

    public boolean isUserAuthenticated() {
        return authenticatedUser;
    }

    public String getLastRawFriendList() {
        return this.rawFriendList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i("IMService is being destroyed", "...");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void exit() {
        timer.cancel();
        socketOperator.exit();
        socketOperator = null;
        this.stopSelf();
    }

    public String signUpUser(String usernameText, String passwordText,
            String emailText) {
        String params = "username=" + usernameText + "&password="
                + passwordText + "&action=" + "signUpUser" + "&email="
                + emailText + "&";

        String result = socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);

        // This is the output of the datastream from the server ie. <data>
        // (bunch of data...etc) </data>
        return result;
    }

    public String addNewFriendRequest(String friendUsername) {
        String params = "username=" + this.username + "&password="
                + this.password + "&action=" + "addNewFriend"
                + "&friendUserName=" + friendUsername + "&";

        String result = socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);

        return result;
    }

    public String sendFriendsReqsResponse(String approvedFriendNames,
            String discardedFriendNames) {
        String params = "username=" + this.username + "&password="
                + this.password + "&action=" + "responseOfFriendReqs"
                + "&approvedFriends=" + approvedFriendNames
                + "&discardedFriends=" + discardedFriendNames + "&";

        String result = socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);

        return result;
    }

    private void parseFriendInfo(String xml) {
        try {
            SAXParser sp = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            sp.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()), new HandlerXML(
                    MessagingService.this));
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void parseMessageInfo(String xml) {
        try {
            SAXParser sp = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            sp.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()), new HandlerXML(
                    MessagingService.this));
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void parseGroupInfo(String xml) {
        try {
            SAXParser sp = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            sp.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()), new HandlerXML(
                    MessagingService.this));
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void parseGroupMessageInfo(String xml) {
        try {
            SAXParser sp = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            sp.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()), new HandlerXML(
                    MessagingService.this));
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateData(InfoOfMessage[] messages, InfoOfFriend[] friends,
            InfoOfGroup[] groups, InfoOfGroupMessage[] groupMessages,
            InfoOfFriend[] unApprovedFriends, String userKey) {
        this.setUserKey(userKey);
        // FriendController.
        IndividualMessageController.setMessagesInfo(messages);
        // Log.i("MESSAGEIMSERVICE","messages.length="+messages.length);
        GroupMessageController.setMessagesInfo(groupMessages);

        int i = 0;
        while (i < messages.length) {
            messageReceived(messages[i].userid, messages[i].messagetext);

            i++;
        }

        int j = 0;
        while (j < groupMessages.length) {
            groupMessageReceived(groupMessages[i].fromUser,
                    groupMessages[i].toGroupId, groupMessages[i].messageText);
            j++;
        }

        // For individual chat
        ControllerOfFriend.setFriendsInfo(friends);
        ControllerOfFriend.setUnapprovedFriendsInfo(unApprovedFriends);

        // For group chat
        ControllerOfGroup.setGroupsInfo(groups);
        // ControllerOfGroup.setUnapprovedGroupsInfo(unapprovedGroups);
    }

    // ************GENERAL METHODS FOR THE GROUP CHAT************

    @Override
    public String createNewGroup(String userName, String groupName)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String params = "username=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.username, "UTF-8")
                + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.password, "UTF-8")
                + "&action=" + "createGroup" + "&groupName=" + groupName + "&";

        String result = socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String addGroupMember() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String sendGroupMessage(String toGroupId, String toGroupName,
            String messageText) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String params = "username=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.username, "UTF-8")
                + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(this.password, "UTF-8")
                + "&toGroupId=" + URLEncoder.encode(toGroupId, "UTF-8")
                + "&messageText=" + URLEncoder.encode(messageText, "UTF-8")
                + "&action=" + URLEncoder.encode("sendGroupMessage", "UTF-8")
                + "&";
        Log.i("PARAMS", params);
        return socketOperator.sendHttpRequest(params);
    }

    @Override
    public String getGroupName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.groupname;
    }
}
```

Websocket Class

```
public class Socketer implements SocketerInterface
{
    Global ipAddress = new Global(); 
    private final String AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://" + ipAddress.getIpAddress() + ":PRIVATE"; // change to your WebAPI Address

    private int listeningPort = 0;

    private static final String HTTP_REQUEST_FAILED = null;

    private HashMap<InetAddress, Socket> sockets = new HashMap<InetAddress, Socket>();

    private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    private boolean listening;

    private class ReceiveConnection extends Thread {
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        public ReceiveConnection(Socket socket) 
        {
            this.clientSocket = socket;
            Socketer.this.sockets.put(socket.getInetAddress(), socket);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
             try {
    //          PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                                    clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;

                 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                 {
                     if (inputLine.equals("exit") == false)  // as long as have noted exited yet, will continuing reading in 
                     {
                         //appManager.messageReceived(inputLine);                        
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         clientSocket.shutdownInput();
                         clientSocket.shutdownOutput();
                         clientSocket.close();
                         Socketer.this.sockets.remove(clientSocket.getInetAddress());
                     }                       
                 }      

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("ReceiveConnection.run: when receiving connection ","");
            }           
        }   
    }

    public Socketer(Manager appManager) {   
    }

    public String sendHttpRequest(String params)
    {       
        URL url;
        String result = new String();
        try 
        {
            url = new URL(AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS);
            HttpURLConnection connection;
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

            out.println(params);
            out.close();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                result = result.concat(inputLine);              
            }
            in.close();         
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           

        if (result.length() == 0) {
            result = HTTP_REQUEST_FAILED;
        }

        // This is the output of the datastream from the server ie. <data> (bunch of data...etc) </data>
        return result;
    }

    public int startListening(int portNo) 
    {
        listening = true;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNo);
            this.listeningPort = portNo;
        } catch (IOException e) {           

            //e.printStackTrace();
            this.listeningPort = 0;
            return 0;
        }

        while (listening) {
            try {
                new ReceiveConnection(serverSocket.accept()).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();              
                return 2;
            }
        }

        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            Log.e("Exception server socket", "Exception when closing server socket");
            return 3;
        }

        return 1;
    }

    public void stopListening() 
    {
        this.listening = false;
    }

    public void exit() 
    {           
        for (Iterator<Socket> iterator = sockets.values().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) 
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket) iterator.next();
            try {
                socket.shutdownInput();
                socket.shutdownOutput();
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) 
            {               
            }       
        }

        sockets.clear();
        this.stopListening();
    }

    public int getListeningPort() {

        return this.listeningPort;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MikeM. I have allot of intents moving throughout the application, or are you referring to the BroadcastReceiver intent?

Comment: @MikeM. Is there a way to discover the source of an intent given that we are in the BroadcastReceiver class?

Comment: @MikeM. I will upload that if it helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58302/discussion-between-eatlon-and-mike-m).

Comment: @MikeM. I added the MessagingService class

Comment: @MikeM. Looking at LogCat, the server is not sending infinitely. As for debugging, I do not know where the infinite loops would be, because I am using the same code for one to one chat (note: this whole thing is powered by websockets) and there are no infinite loops

Comment: @MikeM. Within the user screen, the same message is appearing over and over, in Logcat I see the same database messages the app is receiving, but then only displays the first one and puts it in the SQLite database. Can we open a chat for this?

Comment: @MikeM. Looking at the code, it appears the server may be infinitely  sending messages, anyway to stop it?

Comment: @MikeM. I changed the index, still looping through

Comment: @MikeM. I have uploaded the websocket class as well

Comment: @MikeM. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: I don't know. I'm just saying somewhere in there might be where the infinite loop is starting.

Comment: @MikeM. I do not think so, that allows an open connection with the server and websocket. As for the WEbsocket in general, would the server persist if there was no handshake? Or would it just prevent messages from being sent?

Comment: @MikeM.  Yes, you were correct, when there is a group message in the MySQL database, it infinitely sent to the user. I am using Apache within XAMPP, is there a way to remedy?Or at least notify the server that the message has been received so that it only sends one message?

Comment: Dunno. You'll have to ask a question specifically about those technologies. This question was (originally) about BroadcastReceivers and Intents.